# #import directive not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, flash, importerror

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and I'm creating a C++ App, which is not MFC nor ATL. That app needs to add Flash Player support, and in order to do that, I have to use the statement:

```
#import "C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\Flash.ocx" named_guids
```

For some reason which is driving me mad, this import directive is not working, intellisense shows me: Cannot open file "C:/ProjectName/obj/Flash.tlh"

I've done a lot of reseach on it but no one knows how to solve it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Escape backslashes? "\\" rather than "\"?

Comment: Does exactly the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result of the #import command, the compiler will generate the flash.tli and flash.tlh files. They contain your Flash Player interface declarations.

You may need to modify your linker command line or VC++ directories to add them in.